# Is there a more efficient way to change the style of the clicked buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have about 40 button on the project but my example shows only four. My code is very repetitive and wondering if there's a lighter approach or language? I'd like to hide or change style of the clicked button/s.

```js
$("[data-id='1']").on('click', function() {
  $("[data-id='1']").css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
$("[data-id='2']").on('click', function() {
  $("[data-id='2']").css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
$("[data-id='3']").on('click', function() {
  $("[data-id='3']").css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
$("[data-id='4']").on('click', function() {
  $("[data-id='4']").css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

```css
button {
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  padding: 5px 30px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-id='1' class="hope">1</button>
<button data-id='2' class="hope">2</button>
<button data-id='3' class="hope">3</button>
<button data-id='4' class="hope">4</button>
```

Thanks
http://jsfiddle.net/05cempj7/

Comment: so long as there is a common class applied to all your buttons you can use that to identify and add a single event listener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function operates on all elements having the `.hope` class.

```
$(".hope").on('click', function() {
  $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

If clicked on any hope class `$(".hope")` then `$(this)` reefers to the element that is clicked on.

Comment: `$(this)` is only the button that was clicked

Comment: `$(this)` reefers to the element that is clicked on.

Comment: Perfect. If for arguments sake I had to have multiple buttons with `data-id=2`, could I also have that one change the same as the one clicked? Something like `(this)+data-id`?

Comment: No not like that. Then you need something like this:

`$(".hope").on('click', function() {
  var checkId = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
  $('.hope[data-id='+checkId+']').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});`